# Push Notification to .NET MVC3 application from Windows Azure SQL / WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, azure, notifications, push

Can i have mechinism to have push notification to .NET MVC application once user comes online? Like facebook and gmail? I am going to deploy my app in 3 part.
1) MVC application
2) WCF Service
3) Azure SQL

Everything would in Windows Azure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you might be interested in SignalR.  Here is the link http://signalr.net.  SignalR allows you to push content from the server to the client.  It comes with client side js library and also server side component.  SignalR is very easy to implement and provides a very powerful set of abstractions that otherwise would be very difficult to program.